# Return django validation errors in JSON format

Tags: python, django

Suppose I am building a registration/signup or any form in general for my web app in Django and I want the same form for Web/Android/IOS. So I want the frontend and backend(Django) to communicate via JSON. My question is how can I send validation errors in JSON format if the user on any platform(Web/Android/IOS) gives me invalid data like "the email already exists" type of errors?

I need the best way possible to handle this type of scenarios and well-detailed example/explanation will be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

The form's `errors` attribute has an [`as_json`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) method you can use.

```
if form.is_valid():
    # process valid form
else:
    errors_json = form.errors.as_json()
    ...
```

Note the warning in the docs about escaping the errors to avoid cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: How will the Android/IOS catch these error messages? The errors are just stored in the variable errors_json.

Comment: But I think the response consists of only those files/urls which are present inside the django's project folder.

Comment: can you explain  how to loop through those errors in the js after getting them from the view with ajax

Comment: ok i posted a new question here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648198/how-to-loop-through-django-form-errors-after-getting-them-as-json-with-ajax i hope you help me